# How to check arg type inside a macro_rule?

Tags: rust

How can I check for a specific type inside macro_rules (or even outside)?

I want to emulate function overloading using macro_rules but it appears that I am limited by the lack of type checking. I know I can check for Result and Option enums but I need to see if the argument is a &String or a bool or something else. How can I achieve this?

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($arg:expr) => {
        match $arg {
            // String => {},
            // bool => {},
            // _ => {}
        }
    };
}
```